# how to format the print output in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I get a `RDD[(String, Array[String])]` and two functions,which are meant to find movie names given movie id.

```
 def find_name1( n : String, m: Map[String,String]) = {
    print(n+":")
    println(m.get(n).mkString)
  }
  def find_name2(n:Array[String], m: Map[String,String]) = {
    print("here is what we recommend:")
    for(i<-0 until n.length)
    {
      print(n(i)+":"+m.get(n(i)).mkString+",")
    }
    println()
  }
```

Then I do print work in this way

```
data.foreach{x=>find_name1(x._1,m.toMap)
      find_name2(x._2,m.toMap)}
```

result should be four park, but first looks wired. It is:

```
1375:1694:Apostle, The (1997)
Star Trek III: The Search for Spock (1984)
here is what we recommend:here is what we recommend:1373:Star Trek V: The Final Frontier (1989),1372:Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country (1991),994:Big Night (1996),329:Star Trek: Generations (1994),1810:Primary Colors (1998),2641:Superman II (1980),1120:People vs. Larry Flynt, The (1996),1371:Star Trek: The Motion Picture (1979),281:Nobody's Fool (1994),1635:Ice Storm, The (1997),
```

Why the first two id are not printed as the format: ID:Name. It looks like the print work is not done line by line in RDD:data. Is there any one who can tell me why this happen? How I can format the output as I want.

Comment: if you run this few times, do you get the same result every time?

Comment: @maasg yes, i get same result every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to get such report from an RDD would be to transform the data until you have all items required and then, in a final transformation, produce the actual report.

Also, side-effecting functions are discouraged as they will produce non-deterministic results in a distributed environment (in the case of println, if you were using a cluster, you wouldn't even see them. This only works in local mode, therefore it's not scalable)

I'd suggest the following changes (*):

```
def findMovieTitle(id: String) : String = ???

val recommendationReportRDD = movieDataRDD.map{case (id, recommendations) =>    
    val formatId: String => String = id => s"$id: ${findMovieTitle(id)}"    
    val recomStr = recommendations.map(id => formatId(id)).mkString(","))

    s"${formatId(id)}. We recommend: $recomStr"
}
```

Now, you can flexibly decide what to do with the report.

You can print it up:

```
recommendationReportRDD.collect.foreach(println _)
```

But also, you could save it to a file:

```
recommendationReportRDD.saveAstTextFile("path/to/report.txt")
```

(*) code provided for illustration purposes. Not compiled or tested.

Comment: I got the right format yesterday after I changed m in find_name1 and find_name2 to `m: scala.collection.Map` . I have no idea why it gives me the right format. Now I practice in local mode, if I can't use println in cluster, what commend I should use?

Comment: @G_cy  see this answer :-)  we wouldn't use `println` in a big data application anyway, so when data sizes start to grow, we would write to a db or filesystem for some viz application to pick up from that.

Comment: get you idea! thank you for your sharing ! Do you have any idea about why I can get the right format after changing m's definition.

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything what happens with RDD is done in parallel, so if you want it to do something in linear order you should call `collect()` before such operations.